# Call event listener from background.js in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an event listener in `background.js` as follows:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
 .....
})
```

How can I call this event listener from content script?

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to vice versa, to call event listener from background.js in content script

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You can create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem. When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: If the code you've edited into the question solved your problem, then your question is unclear. As it's stated, your question is about *triggering* the event from your content script. What you have written is that you don't *begin to listen* for the event until your content script messages your background script. There is a big difference between the two. Please clarify your question, so it's clear exactly what it is you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call or basically say trigger any webrequest api event listener from content script. Basically the definition of `onHeadersReceived` is as below on the offical doumentation.

> Fires each time that an HTTP(S) response header is received. Due to
>   redirects and authentication requests this can happen multiple times
>   per request. This event is intended to allow extensions to add,
>   modify, and delete response headers, such as incoming Set-Cookie
>   headers. The caching directives are processed before this event is
>   triggered, so modifying headers such as Cache-Control has no influence
>   on the browser's cache. It also allows you to redirect the request.

Please checkout the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) of the event you are listening to for better clarity and options.

But you can always add custom eventListners on background.js scripts which you are trigger from content scripts using the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) feature. A  simple example is depicted in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple). Where you send a custom message from content script and receive the message on background script. This way you can communicate with background script.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Edited my code using the messaging feature